# Why doesn't pthread_join() suspend the main thread?

Tags: c, linux, unix

Why does the main thread exit while thread_1 and thread_2 are still running.
How do I fix this issue?
Is this error caused by a multi-core CPU?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>

pthread_mutex_t mutex = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
pthread_cond_t cond = PTHREAD_COND_INITIALIZER;

static int i = 1;

void* thread_1(void*);
void* thread_2(void*);

int main(void) {
    pthread_t tid_1;
    pthread_t tid_2;

    pthread_create(&tid_1, NULL, thread_1, (void*)NULL);
    pthread_create(&tid_2, NULL, thread_2, (void*)NULL);
    pthread_join(&tid_1, NULL);
    pthread_join(&tid_2, NULL);

    pthread_mutex_destroy(&mutex);
    pthread_cond_destroy(&cond);

    exit(0);
}

void* thread_1(void* arg) {
    pthread_cleanup_push(pthread_mutex_unlock, &mutex);
    for (i = 1; i < 7; ++i) {
        pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
        printf("thread 1: lock %d\n", __LINE__);
        if (i % 3 == 0) {
            printf("thread 1: pre-signal %d\n", __LINE__);
            pthread_cond_signal(&cond);
            printf("thread 1: after-signal %d\n", __LINE__);
            sleep(1);
        }
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
        printf("thread 1: unlock %d\n\n", __LINE__);
        sleep(1);
    }
    pthread_cleanup_pop(0);

    return (void*)0;
}

void* thread_2(void* arg) {
    pthread_cleanup_push(pthread_mutex_unlock, &mutex);
    while (i < 7) {
        pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
        printf("thread 2: lock %d\n", __LINE__);
        if (i % 3 != 0) {
            printf("thread 2: pre-wait %d\n", __LINE__);
            pthread_cond_wait(&cond, &mutex);
            printf("thread 2: after-wait %d\n", __LINE__);
        }
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
        printf("thread 2: unlock %d\n\n", __LINE__);
        sleep(1);
    }
    pthread_cleanup_pop(0);

    return (void*)0;
}
```

and the gdb debug info:

```
Reading symbols from mutex05...done.
    (gdb) b 1
    Breakpoint 1 at 0x400ad5: file main.c, line 1.
    (gdb) r
    Starting program: /home/myl/Workspace/unix/mutex05/mutex05 
    [Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]
    Using host libthread_db library "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libthread_db.so.1".

    Breakpoint 1, main () at main.c:19
    19        pthread_create(&tid_1, NULL, thread_1, (void *)NULL);
    (gdb) n
    [New Thread 0x7ffff77f5700 (LWP 13524)]
    thread 1: lock 36
    20        pthread_create(&tid_2, NULL, thread_2, (void *)NULL);
    (gdb) n
    thread 1: unlock 45

    [New Thread 0x7ffff6df4700 (LWP 13532)]
    thread 2: lock 59
    21        pthread_join(&tid_1, NULL);
    (gdb) n
    thread 2: pre-wait 62
    22        pthread_join(&tid_2, NULL);
    (gdb) n
    thread 1: lock 36
    thread 1: unlock 45

    24        pthread_mutex_destroy(&mutex);
    (gdb) n
    thread 1: lock 36
    thread 1: pre-signal 39
    thread 1: after-signal 41
    25        pthread_cond_destroy(&cond);
    (gdb) n
    thread 1: unlock 45

    thread 2: after-wait 64
    thread 2: unlock 67

    27        exit(0);
    (gdb) n
    thread 2: lock 59
    thread 2: pre-wait 62
    [Thread 0x7ffff6df4700 (LWP 13532) exited]
    [Thread 0x7ffff77f5700 (LWP 13524) exited]
    [Inferior 1 (process 13520) exited normally]
```

the pthread_mutex_destroy() executed before the thread_1 and thread_2 returned

Answer (score 3):

try

```
pthread_join(tid_1, NULL);  
pthread_join(tid_2, NULL);
```

the [signature](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/pthread_join.html) takes a `pthread_t` instead of `pthread_t*`.

Comment: thanks, the problem solved, but the main thread can't exit. i think the main thread suspend when execute pthread_join(tid_1, NULL), and when both thread_1 and thread_2 exit, the main thread execute pthread_join(tid_2, NULL) so it blocks?

Comment: @myanl:  If the thread has already exited, `pthread_join` will return immediately.  Your main thread does not have to be waiting when the thread exits.

Comment: you should probably change int i to be `volatile` as well.  You may be running into memory barrier issues.

Comment: also once you do a join, the calling thread will wait for the thread to be joined to terminate.  You may have a bug in your code that causes thread two to hang indefinitely.  Start small with two less complex threads to ensure your main thread behaves properly when dealing with the threads, and then add complexity to your threads incrementally.